# use virtual navigation on keyless view

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a view that Unions two tables Table1 and Table2.  This view contains data from Table1 and Table2 along with their respective primary keys Table1Id and Table2Id.  If there is no Table1 or Table2, these ids are set to 0 in the union.

I usually use EntityTypeBuilder to configure these classes, but in this example I have given them attributes to indicate this configuration.
I would like navigation properties on all three classes if at all possible, not EntityFramework doesn't like keyless views.  Are there alternatives or ways to create navigation properties to this keyless view?

```
    [Keyless]
    public class ExampleKeylessUnionView
    {
        public int Table1Id { get; set; }
        public int Table2Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Table1 Table2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Table1
    {
        [Key]
        public int Table1Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ExampleKeylessUnionView View { get; set; }
    }
    public class Table2
    {
        [Key]
        public int Table2Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ExampleKeylessUnionView View { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Navigation properties require a FK to their respective related entity. That could be a null-able `int?`, but not an `int` just defaulting to 0. Entities like that are typically many-to-many joining entities where a Table1 would have a collection of Table2, and Table2 would have a collection of Table1. It may be possible to establish a 1-to-0/1 relationship where Table1.View would have to be Nullable.  This assumes that there would only ever be 1 or 0 records in the UnionView for a particular Table1Id/Table2Id.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a solution to Navigation properties not being allowed with a keyless configuration.